# Error while executing an SSIS package with ODBC connection on SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc

I've created a new SSIS package, it's correctly working using Visual Studio and an ODBC connection :

[image]
[image]

But when I'm trying to execute it using a Job under SQL Server I have this error :

```
Copie t_agence:Error: The component is missing, not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The contact information for this component is "ODBC Source;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;1".
Copie t_agence:Error: The managed pipeline component "Microsoft.SSISODBCSrc" could not be loaded.  The exception was: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SSISODBCSrc' from assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'..
```

I don't remember that an ODBC driver is needed to be install under SQL Server to allow the ececution of a package using an ODBC connection...
Could you give me hand on this please ?

Comment: You'll need to make sure the PostgreSQL ODBC drivers are installed on the server where the package was deployed.  You will also need to setup/create that ODBC connection on the server as well, when you do that on the server set it a "System DSN"

Comment: Also pay attention to 64 bit verse 32 bit.  SQL Server will execute it in 64 bit which means you need the 64 bit drivers on the server and you'd need to setup the ODBC using the 64 bit ODBC manager.  Or configure the job step to use the 32 bit runtime.

Comment: I think you pointed something, I've installed the 64b driver but not the 32b !!
I'll take a look tomorrow at the office, thanks for the idea

Comment: Thx for the idea @TimMylott but it didn't worked :(
I've installed both psqlodbc_12_02_0000-x64 & psqlodbc_12_02_0000-x86 on the serverbut still have the same error message

Comment: where is the DSN configured on the server?  check that.  There are 2 versions of the odbc admin 32bit/64bit.   Set it up in both in the system DSN tab.

Answer (score 3):

Well...
The problem was "just" to select the correct SSMS version here :
[image]

It took me 2 days...
Thanks for your help guys.